# Word order in a sentence

Tags: grammar

Last week I had an appointment with a notary public. How can I say it?

> Ich habe den Termin beim Notar am 28. Juli.

I feel this sentence is not correct.

Answer (score 5):

Your sentence uses the present tense, often used to refer to a future event:

> I have an appointment on July 28.

If you want to express an event in the past, use something like

> Ich hatte den Termin beim Notar am 28. Juli.

or simply

> Der Termin beim Notar war am 28. Juli.

Comment: or the more idiomatic versions where the date is not at the end.

Comment: Why would that be more idiomatic? It all depends on what part of the sentence you want to stress. There's nothing wrong with "Ich hatte am 28. Juli einen Termin", but it's in no way more correct or idiomatic than the other variants.

Comment: Well, the default version has the date not at the end. Putting it there places special emphasis on the date. Why is it not at the end per default? Because "haben" gets complemented by a direct object, not a time. Maybe "idiomatic" is not the best choice of words, but since OP seems to be asking about structure specifically, I think you should at least mention the different options for word order.

Comment: There is a "default version"? I never knew. Putting the date at the end carries no special meaning in my opinion. YMMV.

Comment: YMMV?... so you don't see any difference between "Ich habe am 28. den Termin beim Notar." and "Ich habe den Termin beim Notar am 28."?

Comment: Not really, no. If this is a conversation, a different answer might be given to particular questions, but if it's  simple sentence you can really put the date anywhere you like. If somebody asked my about my appointment with the notary public I would probably have put the date at the end, but this is really a matter of personal preference. Let's not over-analyze this. (Or, I for one won't, for what that's worth.)

Comment: @Emanuel http://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/satzbau/hauptsaetze gives the time before the direct object, which is how I would have done it as well, but Ingmar is right, it mostly is mainly a matter of personal preference and maybe the intention of the speaker.

Comment: @BMWurm... exactly, intention of the speaker. That implies that different orders convey different things. Especially in writing there is a reason why something is where it is and personal preference doesn't have much to do with it.